# getText() Web Element does not contain definition

Tags: selenium

On my selenium script I get an error when trying to use getText:

```
String Text = driver.findElement(By.id("myDiv")).getText();
```

CS1061 'Web Element' does not contain a definition for 'getText' and no accessible extension method 'getText' accepting a first argument of type 'WebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this:

```
String Text = driver.findElement(By.id("myDiv")).Text;
```

The driver is returning the element, and you want the element's contents. By calling the .text, you are accessing this information.